# Input value disappear when click outside it in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am using `react-select` in my application. Using it i have:

```js
import React from "react";

import CreatableSelect from "react-select/creatable";
import { colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

const CreatableMulti = () => {
  const handleChange = (newValue, actionMeta) => {
    console.group("Value Changed");
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };

  return (
    <CreatableSelect
      menuIsOpen={false}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={colourOptions}
    />
  );
};

export default CreatableMulti;
```

ISSUE: after typing the value in the input and after that click outside it, the text from input dissapear. 
Question: How to keep the value inside input and solving the issue above?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-7orh6?file=/example.js:0-516

Answer (score 1):

We have to use `onInputChange` function. For more you can check the official [Doc](https://react-select.com/props#statemanager-props)

Solution:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import CreatableSelect from "react-select/creatable";
import { colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

const CreatableMulti = () => {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (newValue, actionMeta) => {
    console.group("Value Changed");
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };

  const handleInputValue = (str, event) => {
    console.log("string:  ", str, event);
    if (event.action === "menu-close") {
      if (!str) {
        setInputVal(inputVal);
      }
    } else setInputVal(str);
  };

  return (
    <CreatableSelect
      menuIsOpen={false}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={colourOptions}
      onInputChange={handleInputValue}
      inputValue={inputVal}
    />
  );
};

export default CreatableMulti;
```

Comment: AI is overrated, I asked 5 questions and did not get a solution. We still need human programmer like you